# Typescript: make optional prop required if generic type is set

Tags: typescript

I want to do something like

```
export interface Foobar {
  foo: string;
  bar?: any;
}

export interface Foobar<T> {
  bar: T;
}
```

, so that `bar` is an optional prop if no generic type is passed, but has to be of the generic type if one is set... i. e., I want to be able to do

```
const one: Foobar = { foo: 'foo' }; // bar is not required here
const two: Foobar<number> = { foo: 'foo', bar: 123 }; // `bar` is required here
```

The suggestion above throws

> All declarations of 'Foobar' must have identical type parameters.

Is it possible to achieve this in some other way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure what your use case is, but if you can use a [type alias](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-aliases) instead of an interface, then you could define `Foobar` to be something like:

```
type Foobar<T = never> = {
  foo: string;
} & ([T] extends [never] ? { bar?: any } : { bar: T });
```

This uses a [generic parameter default](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#generic-parameter-defaults) to set `T` to `never` if you don't specify it, and a [conditional type](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#conditional-types) to choose either an optional `bar` or a required `bar` depending on the type of `T`.  It works the way you wanted:

```
const one: Foobar = { foo: "foo" }; // bar is not required here
const two: Foobar<number> = { foo: "foo", bar: 123 }; // `bar` is required here
```

Hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nARgQwE4B4AqUC8UB2EAbhKgHy5QDeAUFFAGYIBcUAzsKgJb4DmA3DQC+UAGRQAFAG1MAXSgQAHsAj4AJmyhTCJVPID81KClT7WyfCCgjWVY2lbYhASkE0AxnHwcoXiK3gkNEo7JjhWACIwiOt+KAB6ePtUKC5NfDhgKFQIAEcAVy4ctSgAC1IIDy8fYAB3cNgEE3R8fIBbRFIKPFCWKCiECIAaZNYARgAmAGZYhKSAAxN51M0cgqKIEvKcmiA)

Comment: Yup, this works! But could you please elaborate on why the condition is `[T] extends [never]` and not `T extends never`?

Comment: Because `T extends never ? X : Y`  would be a [distributive conditional type](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#distributive-conditional-types) and wouldn't behave as you expect (specifically, if `T` is `never`, it would yield `never` and not `X`.)

Comment: Just for completion, in my use case I had some issues with using `never` as the default value for `T`. The way I solved it was to write two interfaces, `NonGenericFoobar { foo: string; bar?: any; }` and `GenericFoobar<T> extends NonGenericFoobar { bar: T; }`, and then define the type alias as `type Foobar<T = any> = T extends never ? NonGenericFoobar : GenericFoobar<T>`. It did not work well with the inline types for some reason. [link to code](https://repl.it/@simonhaenisch/SelfassuredCulturedPlan).